# WPF - Opacity property doesn't work the second time

Tags: c#, wpf, opacity

I have the following code:

```
    // Fade out the photo, and after, fade in canvas
double DurationSeconds = duration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;

System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard storyboard = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();

System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation animScreenshot = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DurationSeconds / 3)));
System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetName(animScreenshot, DrawingCanvasTransition.Name);
System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animScreenshot, new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));

// !!!
RectangleTransition.Opacity = 1; // <----------------- PROBLEM IS HERE
RectangleTransition.UpdateLayout();

System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation animRect = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DurationSeconds / 3)));
animRect.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( DurationSeconds * .66);
System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetName(animRect, RectangleTransition.Name);
System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animRect, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.OpacityProperty));

storyboard.Children.Add(animScreenshot);
storyboard.Children.Add(animRect);

// And start!
storyboard.Begin(this);
```

The problem is that the first time the function is called, the animation works perfectly.
The second time, the opacity property doesn't change at all. What could be the problem?
In the debugger, the .Opacity property = 0 even after the line where it should change to 1.
The animations do however work.

Comment: Does RectangleTransition have a brush associated with it so that you are indeed changing the opacity of a color?

Comment: I am changing the opacity of the Rectangle, not the brush.

Comment: @Tiberiu Right but if your Fill on the Rectangle has no brush (color) associated with it changing the opacity will obviously never do anything visually

Comment: Nevermind, I found a fix... Changing the FillBehavior to Stop, because I found out that animations in WPF lock the property unless instructed not to.

Comment: @Tiberiu Add the solution as an answer for others that may stumble upon this...

Comment: I would like to introduce to you the `using <namespace>` construct...

Answer (score 3):

Aside from setting FillBehavior to Stop, as you mentioned there are a couple of other ways to make sure this property locking doesn't happen:

- Remove the animation object by handling the animation's Completed event. (e.g., "storyboard.Remove(myObject)")
- Make the animation reversible by setting the AutoReverse (obviously this doesn't work if you want the end result to be different from how you started).

This is actually a very common source of confusion and MSDN has a [decent-sized writeup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20269503/138078).
You should change the opacity again via an animation or somehow disable your animation.