# Changing opacity from code-behind

Tags: wpf, animation, opacity

Why has the following event in a Window code-behind no effect?

```
void about_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // TopLevel.Opacity = 1.0, Splashscreen.Opacity = 0.0
   TopLevel.Opacity = 0.1;
   // still: TopLevel.Opacity = 1.0
   Splashscreen.Opacity = 1.0;
   // still: Splashscreen.Opacity = 0.0
}
```

The opacity values do not change.

I discovered that the following Trigger is the cause of my issue:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource splashscreenanimation}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

When I remove it the code-behind is working.

For completeness, this is the animation:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="splashscreenanimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Splashscreen"
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.900">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5"
                                    Value="0" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="TopLevel"
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0.900">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5"
                                    Value="1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

[**Solution**](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/08/21/removing-the-value-applied-by-an-animation/): In code behind you can remove the animation by first executing:   `Splashscreen.BeginAnimation(UserControl.OpacityProperty, null);`
(Splashscreen is a UserControl).
I also tried adding `FillBehavior="HoldEnd"` or `FillBehavior="Stop"` to the Storyboard but did'nt get it to work properly.

Comment: I would disagree with your last comment... that works fine for me. Perhaps you could show a simplified version of your XAML that still exhibits this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again you and again the same issue with dependency property value precedence.

Take a look at the priorities.

1. Property system coercion.
2. Active animations, or animations with a Hold behavior. In order to have any practical effect, an animation of a property must be able to have precedence over the base (unanimated) value, even if that value was set locally.
3. Local value. A local value might be set through the convenience of the "wrapper" property, which also equates to setting as an attribute or property element in XAML, or by a call to the SetValue API using a property of a specific instance.

In your case animation takes over.

Your code here is #3. You are setting the local value but animation still takes over.

```
void about_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // TopLevel.Opacity = 1.0, Splashscreen.Opacity = 0.0
   TopLevel.Opacity = 0.1;
   // still: TopLevel.Opacity = 1.0
   Splashscreen.Opacity = 1.0;
   // still: Splashscreen.Opacity = 0.0
}
```

I hope now you finally understand how priorities work. :) :) :)